# wine doesn't show persian(or arabic) words

Tags: wine

I installed Winehq but when I open a program which has Persian(or Arabic) words it doesn't shows the words and shows square instead of words!

What I have to do?

Comment: which program? have you checked Firefox.exe? Does it work well?

Comment: I checked a software which I download it from raidcall.com

Comment: and I think it has problem with other software which has persian font!

Comment: I'm not sure but try to install tahoma (or any font you know is applicable) both to linux and in wine (at least put them in fonts folder of wine's drive C:). However I have Firefox installed in wine and it shows arabic/persian sites without problem.

Comment: Which version of wine you are using? (I think Arabic support for GUI added in 1.6, but still not well supported in Rich Text Input box)

Answer (score 0):

You try to copy fonts to wine path. `/home/<usrename>/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts` This work for me.